# Why is not parity transformation just a rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, mathematical-physics, linear-transformations

I'm a bit confused about parity transformations (reflections).
A parity operator $\pi$ takes a vector $(x, y, z)$ to $(-x, -y, -z)$. So in a $3$ dimensional space this takes a vector and points it along its "old tail".. I know that $\pi$ has determinant $-1$ so this can't be done with an $SO(3)$ matrix (rotation), but in my head it doesn't quite work.. I mean I can totally see a vector being taken and continuously moved to the antipodal point! For instance if you have $(0, 0, 1)$ I can take it to $(0, 0, -1)$ by rotating it 180° around the $x$ axis for instance, this being done with an orthogonal matrix! And isn't that a reflection?!?

Thanks!!

Comment: For any vector $v\in\mathbb R^3$ there is some rotation that maps it to $-v$, but there is no one rotation that maps *every* vector $v$ to $-v$. For example, rotating by $180^\circ$ about the $x$-axis maps $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,0,-1)$ but does not map $(1,0,0)$ to $(-1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rotate any single vector to its antipodal vector. You cannot rotate *all vectors at once* to their antipodes by a single rotation, or even by a composition of rotations (for instance, for a single rotation the vectors on the axis won't move at all). The orientation is the simplest explanation why this is not possible. Try for some familiar shape (for instance the contour of your country) drawing all the antipodal points on a sphere, and you will see that you get an isometric image, but that it has the opposite orientation.

For instance, here it is for the U.S.A.
[image: antipodes of the contours of the U.S.A.]

Comment: But in an even dimensional space, can't we say that parity is just a rotation?

Comment: @TobiasFritzm What is certain is that minus the identity preserves orientation if and only if the dimension is even. Whether in arbitrary dimension one calls any isometry that preserves orientation a rotation is another matter; personally I would not unless the operation can be written as the composition of two reflections, which excludes minus the identity when the dimension is more than 2